# How to print a custom grid app?

Tags: rally

I have added a print button and a PrintDialog to my custom app and now need to write a print function. 
Do I need to open up a new window and build a table containing the grid data formatted with css styles fitted to A4 paper size or is there something built into Rally that I can use? 
I am new to Rally and Ext JS, so any advice would be appreciated!

```
Ext.create('Rally.ui.dialog.PrintDialog', {
          height: 250,
          autoShow: true,
          autoCenter: false,
          shouldShowFormatOptions: false,
          defaultTitle: 'Book Of Work Report',
          listeners: {
                print: function(event) {
                //How do I print a grid?         
            },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your inclination is correct - the best option here is to open a window that you populate with table output/grid content and apply whatever CSS formatting you prefer. Rally doesn't have any server-side printing output functionality (at least that is exposed to AppSDK2).

Comment: Thanks for you comment, I did as discussed and created a fairly good looking report!

Comment: Nice work! Would be great if you could post a sample of your code as a follow-up answer - could help others looking to do the same thing!

Answer (score 1):

To print the grid, I created a Rally.data.WsapiDataStore and loaded the store into an array. I passed this array(StoreData) to the below function which opens a print window displaying the grid in a table.

```
_printDetails: function(Storedata) {

        var myData = Storedata;    
        var htmlTable ='<table>';
        htmlTable +='<width="100%">';   

    var r,c;                   
        for(r= 0 ; r<myData.length; r++){   
            htmlTable+= '<tr>';
            for(c = 0 ; c<myData[0].length; c++){    
                htmlTable+='<td>'+myData[r][c]+'</td>';         
            }
            htmlTable+='</tr>';
        }
        htmlTable+='</table>'; 

       var cssTable = '<style type="text/css">';
        cssTable +='table {border-collapse:collapse;...}';
        cssTable +='th {color:#080808;border-bottom-style: solid; ...}';
        cssTable +='tr {color:#000000; border-bottom-style: solid; ..}';
        cssTable +='td {padding:3px 4px; text-align:left; vertical-align:top;}';
        cssTable +='#filter {text-align:left; ...}';    
        cssTable += '</style>';

        var printwindow=window.open('', '', 'width=1000,height=500');
        var myDate = new Date;
        printwindow.document.write('<div id="todayDate">' + Ext.Date.format(myDate,'F j, Y, g:i a') + '</div>');            
        printwindow.document.write('<div id="header">Book Of Work Report</div>');
        printwindow.document.write('<div id="filter"><p>' + this._GetFilterString() + '</p></div>');
        printwindow.document.write(htmlTable);
        printwindow.document.write(cssTable);   
        printwindow.document.close();
        printwindow.focus();
        printwindow.print();
        printwindow.close();
    },
```